# sql - php query, if specific column is zero dont INSERT

Tags: php, sql

I have a query which INSERT values INTO table 'material_weight'

here it is:

```
$sql_material = "INSERT INTO `material_weight`
    (mat_record_id, material_weight, material_name)
    VALUES
    ((select MAX(record_id) FROM truck_records), '$material_wei_1', '$material_1'), 
    ((select MAX(record_id) FROM truck_records), '$material_wei_2', '$material_2'), 
    ((select MAX(record_id) FROM truck_records), '$material_wei_3', '$material_3'), 
    ((select MAX(record_id) FROM truck_records), '$material_wei_4', '$material_4'), 
    ((select MAX(record_id) FROM truck_records), '$material_wei_5', '$material_5'), 
    ((select MAX(record_id) FROM truck_records), '$material_wei_6', '$material_6'), 
    ((select MAX(record_id) FROM truck_records), '$material_wei_7', '$material_7'), 
    ((select MAX(record_id) FROM truck_records), '$material_wei_8', '$material_8'), 
    ((select MAX(record_id) FROM truck_records), '$material_wei_9', '$material_9'), 
    ((select MAX(record_id) FROM truck_records), '$material_wei_10', '$material_10')    ";
```

i want a if statement, IF $material_wei_1 or $material_wei_2 ... equal whith zero do not INSERT this row.

I try to understand the IF syntax but with no luck, here is what i tried...

```
$sql_material = "INSERT INTO `material_weight`
    (mat_record_id, material_weight,    material_name)
    VALUES
    ((select MAX(record_id) FROM truck_records), '$material_wei_1', '$material_1'), 

    if( '$material_wei_2' = 0, ((select MAX(record_id) FROM truck_records), '$material_wei_2', '$material_2') , ),

    ((select MAX(record_id) FROM truck_records), '$material_wei_3', '$material_3'),...
```

is something wrong with IF syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing these values in as parameters into the query.  So my first reaction is to fix the application.

However, you can do this in the query.  Use a subquery to bring the parameters together and just use a `WHERE` clause in the outer query.

The following query does this an also filters out the repeated subquery, so this should be faster than your original version:

```
INSERT INTO material_weight (mat_record_id, material_weight, material_name)
    SELECT mat_record_id, material_weight, material_name
    FROM ((SELECT '$material_wei_1' as material_weight, '$material_1' as material_name) UNION ALL
          (SELECT '$material_wei_2' as material_weight, '$material_2' as material_name) UNION ALL
          . . .
         ) m CROSS JOIN  
         (SELECT MAX(record_id) as mat_record_id FROM truck_records) tr
    WHERE material_weight > 0;
```

Comment: Sorry but it' s not working. No records find in table 'material_weight'.